# How to unregister wpf clickonce application at the time of uninstallaion?

Tags: c#, wpf, registry, uninstallation

I am creating an application in which I am registering users when they use application first time by storing user information into the registry. From the second time use of application user will not see registration dialog box.
My question is about unregistering the user(Deleting registry entry). how can I delete registry entry at time of uninstallation of clickonce application ? any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong storage mechanism. [You should use user.config instead.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This will ensure that your uninstallation will remove the data, since it is stored with your program.

As an added benefit. Your computer with multiple users will be able to have multiple users in your application.